# Is version 17.06.2 of docker compatible with 1.12.6?

Tags: docker, upgrade

I have an old docker release having version 1.12.6. Is it safe to upgrade it to the current version? At the moment it's 17.06.2 that can be found in `docker-ce` deb package. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and It's running several containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are two different products. 1.12.6 is a recent version of the commercial [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/cs-engine/1.13/release-notes/), while 17.06 is the [Community Edition](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-ce/). I would test changes carefully as switching off commercial may cause feature incompatibilities.